# How to join tables with multiple conditions in sql?

Tags: sql

I have two tables displayed here:

[image]

I want to select product.maker only if all his product.model are in table pc.
So, for the same maker next condition must be true:

```
product.model = pc.model
```

Comment: `WHERE product.model = pc.model` ... Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Keep the join condition's in `ON` clause instead of `where` clause which is more readable

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.  Your question is more ambiguous than you may realize.

Comment: Whatever.  It's still basic stuff.

Comment: You should consider doing join on primary key (integer identifier column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I want to select product.maker only if all his product.model are in
>   table pc."

I interpret this as saying that you want a list of makers such that every model assigned to the maker is in the `pc` table.  This is a bit more subtle than a simple join.  It is more of a `left join` with an aggregation and appropriate conditions:

```
select p.maker
from product p left join
     pc
     on p.model = pc.model
group by p.maker
having count(*) = count(pc.model);
```

The `having` condition is one way of verifying that there is a match for every model in `product`.